# Crash - Notification - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS - Namespace SIGNAL

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, crash, exc-bad-access

Kindly share your thoughts/suggestion on below crash.

Seeing some strange crashes and these crashes are not reproducible from my end but users reported so many similar crashes.Crash log says application is crashed in thread 0 and after the `__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__` call in thread 0 I can see a trace `0   ??? 000000000000000000 0 + 0`...what does it mean?

Below is a sample crash log.All other crash logs looks same as below.

```
>Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
>
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
>
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

>Thread 0 name:
>
Thread 0 Crashed:
>
**0   ???                               000000000000000000 0 + 0**
>
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ede22c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20 (CFNotificationCenter.c:650)
>
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181edd930 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400 (CFNotificationCenter.c:164)
>
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181edd6ac ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1031)
>
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181f4cb9c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504 (CFXNotificationRegistrar.m:163)
>
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181e1fbf4 _CFXNotificationPost + 376 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1028)
>
6   Foundation                      0x00000001829256bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68 (NSNotification.m:482)
>
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187fab748 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 268 (UIApplication.m:6227)
>
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188085668 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128 (UIViewController.m:5900)
>
9   UIKit                           0x0000000187fab5e8 -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 100 (UIApplication.m:6215)
>
10  UIKit                           0x0000000187fabb30 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 692 (UIApplication.m:6323)
>
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187fa3478 -[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 320 (UIApplication.m:2962)
>
12  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183ae3904 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:158)
>
13  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183ae3770 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176 (FBSSerialQueue.m:177)
>
14  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183ae3b18 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:206)
>
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ef2278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1943)
>
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ef1bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524 (CFRunLoop.c:1989)
>
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181eef7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804 (CFRunLoop.c:2821)
>
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181e1e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
>
19  UIKit                           0x0000000187d89b04 -[UIApplication _run] + 608 (UIApplication.m:2638)
>
20  UIKit                           0x0000000187d84888 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4091)
>
21  XXXXXX                          0x0000000101745348 0x100024000 + 24253256
>
22  XXXXXX                          0x00000001017455a0 UIApplicationMain + 164
>
23  XXXXXX                          0x00000001015eacf0 main + 368 (main.swift:14)
>
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180e005b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Can you please add any relevant code ?

Comment: @Midhun MP :Crash does not point to any piece of code or class.And there is not much information in crash log.

Comment: @user3608500 did you figure this out? Fighting a similar crash

Comment: Are you using adobe sdk for sitecatalyst tracking?

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in your project? If you do, check the target memberships on all your classes.